# Xmonad, Couldnt match type ‘ModifiedLayout (Sublayout (ModifiedLayout SmartBorder Simplest)) l0 a0’ with ‘GHC.Word.Word64’

Tags: haskell, xmonad

Trying to learn Haskell and decided to try the xmonad wm as a way to learn, and although I've managed to clear most errors on my own I seem to wrap my head around this last two, which are basically the same mistake.

If anyone can nudge me in the write direction of what type of error this is I'd appreciate,
my guess was that it was a missing import however if that is the case I cant seem to find it

Console error

```
• Couldn't match type ‘GHC.Word.Word64’
                  with ‘ModifiedLayout
                          (Sublayout (ModifiedLayout SmartBorder Simplest)) l a’
     arising from a functional dependency between:
       constraint ‘XMonad.Layout.MultiToggle.Transformer
                     StdTransformers
                     (ModifiedLayout
                        (Sublayout (ModifiedLayout SmartBorder Simplest)) l a)’
         arising from a use of ‘avoidStruts’
       instance ‘XMonad.Layout.MultiToggle.Transformer
                   StdTransformers Window’
         at <no location info>
 • In the expression:
     avoidStruts
       $ mouseResize
           $ windowArrange
               $ T.toggleLayouts floats
                   $ mkToggle (NBFULL ?? NOBORDERS ?? EOT) myDefaultLayout
   In an equation for ‘myLayoutHook’:
       myLayoutHook
         = avoidStruts
             $ mouseResize
                 $ windowArrange
                     $ T.toggleLayouts floats
                         $ mkToggle (NBFULL ?? NOBORDERS ?? EOT) myDefaultLayout
         where
             myDefaultLayout
               = tall ||| mstack ||| full ||| threeCol ||| threeRow ||| floats
 • Relevant bindings include
     myLayoutHook :: ModifiedLayout
                       XMonad.Hooks.ManageDocks.AvoidStruts
                       (ModifiedLayout
                          MouseResize
                          (ModifiedLayout
                             XMonad.Layout.WindowArranger.WindowArranger
                             (XMonad.Layout.ToggleLayouts.ToggleLayouts
                                (ModifiedLayout Rename ((->) (l a)))
                                (XMonad.Layout.MultiToggle.MultiToggle
                                   (XMonad.Layout.MultiToggle.HCons
                                      StdTransformers
                                      (XMonad.Layout.MultiToggle.HCons StdTransformers EOT))
                                   (Choose
                                      (ModifiedLayout
                                         Rename
                                         (ModifiedLayout
                                            (Sublayout (ModifiedLayout SmartBorder Simplest))
                                            ResizableTall))
                                      (Choose
                                         (ModifiedLayout
                                            Rename
                                            (ModifiedLayout
                                               (Sublayout (ModifiedLayout SmartBorder Simplest))
                                               (Mirror ResizableTall)))
                                         (Choose
                                            (ModifiedLayout Rename ((->) (l a)))
                                            (Choose
                                               (ModifiedLayout
                                                  Rename
                                                  (ModifiedLayout
                                                     (Sublayout
                                                        (ModifiedLayout SmartBorder Simplest))
                                                     ThreeCol))
                                               (Choose
                                                  (ModifiedLayout
                                                     Rename
                                                     (ModifiedLayout
                                                        (Sublayout
                                                           (ModifiedLayout SmartBorder Simplest))
                                                        (Mirror ThreeCol)))
                                                  (ModifiedLayout Rename ((->) (l a))))))))))))
                       (ModifiedLayout
                          (Sublayout (ModifiedLayout SmartBorder Simplest)) l a)
       (bound at xmonad.hs:151:1)
 |
151 | myLayoutHook = avoidStruts $ mouseResize $ windowArrange $ T.toggleLayouts floats
 |
```

The second error is basicaly the same but starts Couldn't match type ‘ModifiedLayout
(Sublayout (ModifiedLayout SmartBorder Simplest)) l0 a0’
with ‘GHC.Word.Word64’
So the other way around
I am going to leave my import section and the parts of code from the errors

```
-- Impots

    -- Base
import XMonad
import System.Exit
import System.IO
import qualified XMonad.StackSet as W

    -- Actions
import XMonad.Actions.WithAll (sinkAll, killAll)
import XMonad.Actions.MouseResize

    -- Data
import Data.Monoid
import Data.Maybe (fromJust)
import qualified Data.Map   as M

  -- Hooks
import XMonad.Hooks.DynamicLog (dynamicLogWithPP, wrap, xmobarPP, xmobarColor, shorten, PP(..))
import XMonad.Hooks.ManageDocks (avoidStruts, docksEventHook, manageDocks, ToggleStruts(..))
import XMonad.Hooks.ManageHelpers (isFullscreen, doFullFloat)
import XMonad.Hooks.EwmhDesktops
import XMonad.Hooks.WorkspaceHistory
import XMonad.Hooks.FadeInactive

    -- Utils
import XMonad.Util.Run
import XMonad.Util.EZConfig

    -- Layouts
import XMonad.Layout.ThreeColumns
import XMonad.Layout.SimplestFloat
import XMonad.Layout.ResizableTile

    -- Layouts Modifiers
import XMonad.Layout.LayoutModifier
import XMonad.Layout.NoBorders
import XMonad.Layout.Spacing
import XMonad.Layout.SubLayouts
import XMonad.Layout.WindowNavigation
import XMonad.Layout.WindowArranger (windowArrange, WindowArrangerMsg(..))
import XMonad.Layout.Simplest
import XMonad.Layout.Renamed
import XMonad.Layout.MultiToggle (mkToggle, single, EOT(EOT), (??))
import XMonad.Layout.MultiToggle.Instances (StdTransformers(NBFULL, MIRROR, NOBORDERS))
import qualified XMonad.Layout.ToggleLayouts as T (toggleLayouts, ToggleLayout(Toggle))
import qualified XMonad.Layout.MultiToggle as MT (Toggle(..))

-- EndImpots
```

Section of code from Error 1

```
-- LayoutHook
myLayoutHook = avoidStruts $ mouseResize $ windowArrange $ T.toggleLayouts floats <--- ERROR LINE
                     $ mkToggle (NBFULL ?? NOBORDERS ?? EOT) myDefaultLayout
                        where
                                   myDefaultLayout =      tall
                                                            ||| mstack
                                                            ||| full
                                                            ||| threeCol
                                                            ||| threeRow
                                                            ||| floats

-- EndLayouts
```

Section of code from Error 2

```
main :: IO ()
main = do
    xmproc <- spawnPipe "xmobar /home/rodrigo/.config/xmobar/xmobar.config"
    xmonad $ ewmh def
        { manageHook = (isFullscreen --> doFullFloat) <+> myManageHook <+> manageDocks
         , modMask              = myModMask
         , terminal             = myTerminal
         , focusFollowsMouse    = myFocusFollowsMouse
         , clickJustFocuses     = myClickJustFocuses
         , borderWidth          = myBorderWidth
         , workspaces           = myWorkspaces
         , normalBorderColor    = myNormalBorderColor
         , focusedBorderColor   = myFocusedBorderColor
         , mouseBindings        = myMouseBindings
         , layoutHook           = myLayoutHook <--- ERROR LINE
         , logHook = workspaceHistoryHook <+> myLogHook <+> dynamicLogWithPP xmobarPP
                    { ppOutput = \x -> hPutStrLn xmproc x
                      , ppCurrent = xmobarColor "#0e7a0d" ""
                      , ppVisible = xmobarColor "#ffffff" "" .clickable
                      , ppHidden = xmobarColor "#ffffff" "" .clickable
                      , ppHiddenNoWindows = xmobarColor "#ffffff" "" .clickable

                    }


        } `additionalKeysP` myKeys
```

Comment: This is a type error. You may be better served by reading an introductory text like Learn You a Haskell for Great Good.

Comment: @R.FALLEN your problem is in the last part of the type error. `(ModifiedLayout (Sublayout (ModifiedLayout SmartBorder Simplest)) l a)` should be `Window`... I Think, I am not a xmonad user. Could you share the definition of the layouts forming `myDefaultLayout`; specially the definition of `floats`

Comment: Do you still get the type error if you remove all those layout modifiers and just use `myLayoutHook = myDefaultLayout`? If yes, we'll likely have a much less complicated type error to look at; if not, you might try to gradually add the modifiers back to find which one is related to the error. Either way, I suggest adding the definitions of the layouts used in `myDefaultLayout`, as lsmor suggests.